# Discouraged dealing with spaces in path strings with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, path, spaces

I have this piece of code that basically checks if one or more files exist. It works when I search for one file, but it doesn't when I try to search for more. I tried to define an array that takes a string of the path of the file to look for, and then check its existence. But I noticed because there is a space in the path, it won't work. I tried all the combinations I could with simple quotes, double quotes, escaping quotes, nothing...

I don't want to create a specific function for that, just to make things work, keep it simple. Could you please help ?

EDIT : to make the script work, add this : $LogSb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
and you might want to add some output because by default everything goes silently into a "log" string builder.

```
##Checkink files containing my functions
#
$Fonctions = "C:\Program Files\scheduler\jobs\SuivideProd\OLAP\PlusProchesVoisins.ps1", "C:\Program Files\scheduler\jobs\SuivideProd\OLAP\OrdreProcess.ps1"
#Tried something like this before, same error :
#$Fonctions = @()
#$Fonctions += "C:\'Program Files'\scheduler\jobs\SuivideProd\OLAP\PlusProchesVoisins.ps1"
#$Fonctions += "C:\'Program Files'\scheduler\jobs\SuivideProd\OLAP\OrdreProcess.ps1"
foreach ($fonc in $Fonctions) {
  if ((Test-Path $fonc) -eq $True) {
    [void]$LogSb.append("`n").appendline($("Le fichier contenant la fonction $(split-path $fonc -Leaf) a été trouvé."))
    #dot source the file if existing
    . $Fonctions
  } else {
    [void]$LogSb.append("`n").appendline($("Le fichier contenant la fonction $fonc n'a pas été trouvé."))
    throw ("Le fichier contenant la fonction $(split-path $fonc -Leaf) n'a pas été trouvé")
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I spotted your problem, but in the future when your problem involves an error you should show us what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first way of defining the array is fine. Your second method (using `@()` and `+=`) does not need `'`s around `Program Files` (the extra apostrophes actually make the paths incorrect).

Upon reading through it, I think your problem is that you are dot-sourcing the *array* rather than an individual file. You are doing `. $Fonctions` when you probably mean to do `. $fonc`, which is the `foreach` variable holding a single file path.

Comment: OMG ! I spent two hours on this... Since I was traping erros and display only its $_.Message, I didn't pay attention to the exact error and thought it was because of the array construction. Thank you very much anyway.